# Why am I getting logged out of all SE sites?

Tags: support, bug

I haven't been able to track it down, but it seems that every week or so I get logged out of all SE sites - Ask Ubuntu, Super User, Stack Overflow, all of em.

What's causing this, and how can I fix it?  I don't like having to go through the whole login ritual.

Comment: And you never logout manually from any of them? Does this happen independent of which UA you use to access the sites?

Comment: I use my Wordpress login (which doesn't get logged out on wordpress.com) to log into all of them.  I NEVER log out ever.

Comment: And part 2... Does this happen independent of which UA you use to access the sites?

Comment: I assume you mean User Account?  If so, I only use 1.  If not, then what DO you mean?

Comment: No I mean [User Agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent), typically a browser such as Chrome or Firefox but there is a native Android agent.

Comment: @Robert few people know what is UA or understand what is a User Agent. Much more common term is browser. So Daniel, what browser are you using to access the sites? What Operating System?

Comment: Ah.  @RobertLongson I use Safari on Mac on one machine 99.5% of the time.  I use Safari on Mac on another machine 0.5% of the time.  I get logged out on both.

Comment: I understand what a User Agent is @ShadowWizard, but the acronym just didn't click.  Safari can emulate just about any User Agent, so if you need me to test I can.

Comment: Like this @ShadowWizard http://imgur.com/a/8Wy8L

Comment: I think it would be worth trying Chrome of Firefox for a week or two to see if you have the same problem with either of those browsers. That way we could narrow down the problem a little.

Comment: Well, the crucial thing is cookies, maybe you have something that periodically clears them? Some security software, perhaps?

Comment: Nope.  Unless Safari does it in and of itself.

Comment: @RobertLongson I'll try using Firefox/Chrome for a while and see if that helps.

Comment: Happening daily for me with Safari

Comment: I said I would use Firefox @RobertLongson, but like usual I forget.  I've been using Safari since we last spoke and I haven't gotten logged out.